# Delete from MYSQL where value is a static string plus a search result

Tags: mysql

I have a messaging system that uses simple strings such as "function:value" where function is the action I want to perform and value is a key into a table. But what if I want to delete? Is there a way to essentially do this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE message = 'function:'+(SELECT key FROM table2 WHERE val = 'someval')
```

So that it deletes any message of the form "function:" string concatenated with any result from the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE message IN (SELECT CONCAT('function:', key) FROM table2 WHERE val = 'someval')
```

Comment: Wa ha! So that's how you put all those pieces together! Thanks!